# Set instance tags for elastic beanstalk using cloud formation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I am using AWS CloudFormation to create an ElasticBeanstalk application, with an auto-scaling group and launch configuration.  I am trying to apply tags to the ec2 instances that are automatically created with the Elastic Beanstalk app.  I have tried a number of option_settings for the ElasticBeanstalk environment, none of them work. Can someone please provide example CloudFormation JSON for setting instance tags when creating an elastic beanstalk environment using cloud formation?

Comment: Check this developer guide http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ec2.html#scenario-ec2-instance-with-vol-and-tags

Comment: Beanstalk does not allow set tags to instances directly, try setting tags for your `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment` definition.

Comment: I'd agree with @Shibashis, to complement their response, here is the reference - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html#cfn-beanstalk-environment-templatename